# BULK INSERT import text file

Tags: database, csv, bulkinsert, arabic

When I import a CSV or text file and bulk insert it into my database, the process successfully adds all record to the table.

My problem is that the inserted string is in Arabic, which appears as symbols in my database table. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I use Sql DB, Note that when i insert cmd nonquery it store correctly in DB but when I use bulk insert this problem is appear.

Comment: I've added some more info, if it still doesn't work please specify exactly what you're currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

**Insert using query**

You need to choose an Arabic collation for your varchar/char columns or use Unicode (nchar/nvarchar).

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    MyArabicColumn VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS,
    MyNVarCharColumn NVARCHAR(100)
)
```

Both columns should work.

**Bulk Insert from file**

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188289.aspx) explains how to bulk insert unicode characters.

*Test Table*

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
CREATE TABLE myTestUniCharData (
   Col1 smallint,
   Col2 nvarchar(50),
   Col3 nvarchar(50)
   );
```

*Bulk Insert*

`DATAFILETYPE='widechar'` allows the use of Unicode character format when bulk importing data.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
BULK INSERT myTestUniCharData 
   FROM 'C:\myTestUniCharData-w.Dat' 
   WITH (
      DATAFILETYPE='widechar',
      FIELDTERMINATOR=','
   ); 
GO
SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 FROM myTestUniCharData;
GO
```

Comment: <code>
//query to read data from txt file and insert it in the tabel in DB
//textBox1.Text is contain the path and name of .txt file
//comboBox1 is contain all tabels im DB
cmd = new SqlCommand(@"BULK INSERT " + comboBox1.SelectedValue + " FROM '" + textBox1.Text + @"' WITH (DATAFILETYPE='widechar',KEEPIDENTITY,Keepnulls,FIRSTROW = 2, fieldterminator = "+@"',\t', rowterminator =" + @" '\n')", cn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
</code>

Comment: Can you please add this to your question with proper formatting?